# How to reduce the space between attribute dropdowns in WooCommerce product page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, html-table, product

The space between attribute dropdowns is big, also the space between the dropdown and the add to cart button is big too, how could I reduce the space? please see the image and the link  [link](https://www.pmvision.ca/shop/oracle-primavera-p6-training-course-primavera-p6-professional-quebec/)

[image]

The following didn't work:

```php
.single-product div.product table.variations tr .value {
    margin-bottom: .5em; /* Reduced space on all dropdowns except last one */
}
.single-product div.product table.variations tr:last-child .value {
    margin-bottom: 1em; /* Normal space on last dropdown */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the end of your stylesheet:

```
.variations tr, .variations td, .variations th{
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important
}
```

to override to style(s) above it.

Answer (score 2):

To reduce the space between attribute dropdowns, try the following:

```css
.woocommerce div.product form.cart .variations th,
.woocommerce div.product form.cart .variations td,
.woocommerce div.product form.cart .variations tr
{
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
.woocommerce div.product form.cart .variations tr
{
    margin-bottom: .25 !important; /* Here adjust the space */
}
```